# By click on first Accordion tab second tab gets hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I'm having a problem with Accordion tab . when I click on first accordion tab to open the second one gets hidden automatically.
Can you guys please help me out why this is happening.

https://www.lunaandsolis.com/products/plant-based-omega-3-liquid-drops
password to view page: Eastoft2021

I have also tried Javascript code to hide and display but it still didn't worked.

```
   {% for block in section.blocks %}
              <div class="product__accordion accordion " style="display: block; ">
                <details id="Details-{{ block.id }}" >
                  <summary>
                    <div class="summary__title">
                      <h2 class="h4 accordion__title inline-richtext">
                        {{ block.settings.title }}
                      </h2>
                    </div>
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 10 10" class="icon icon-caret" style="width: 15px;">
                    <rect x="1" y="4" width="8" height="2" fill="currentColor"></rect>
                    <rect x="4" y="1" width="2" height="8" fill="currentColor"></rect>
                  </svg>


                  </summary>
                  <div class="accordion__content rte" id="ProductAccordion-fda6e785-4c70-4aa3-b420-375a5ffe10d2-template--16791374168298__main">
                  {{ block.settings.content }}
                </div>
                </details>
              </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

```
this is the code for accordion
```

```
.accordion summary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.accordion .summary__title {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.accordion .summary__title + .icon-caret {
  height: 15px;
}
.accordion + .accordion {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: none;
}



.accordion__title {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: calc(100% - 6rem);
  min-height: 1.6rem;
  margin: 0;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size:16px!important;
  font-weight:400!important;
}

.accordion .icon-accordion {
  align-self: center;
  fill: rgb(var(--color-foreground));
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 20px;
}

.accordion details[open] > summary .icon-caret {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.accordion__content {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0 0.6rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fairly [simple example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) to solve this issue.

Apparently you are working with Shopify syntax (liquid). Then you can add javascript code to the tags:

```
<script>
...
</script>
```